# How to differentiate between an RTOS and Linux?

Tags: c, ubuntu, rtos, qnx

I've a QNX RTOS and Ubuntu 17.10 running. Problem is, other than the fact that QNX is an RTOS, I don't have any proof that it behaves like a RT system. What kind of application should I run on each OS which can give me a clear differentiation between the RT response of an RTOS and Ubuntu?

I ran a signal handler(interrupt handler) program on both to see which one would catch the interrupt first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void sig_hand(int sig) {
    printf("signal received\n");
    exit(0);
}

void *sigfun(void *arg) {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_hand);
    while(printf("Thread running\n"));
    return NULL;
}


int main(void) {
    pthread_t th;

    pthread_create(&th,NULL,sigfun,NULL);
    pthread_join(th,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that while a thread keeps printing `Thread Running`, QNX will fetch the interrupt and stop the thread faster compared to Ubuntu. However, I see no difference and probably this is not the right application to find out the faster RT response.
Can anyone suggest me a better way to clearly differentiate between an RTOS and Ubuntu?

Comment: Who are you trying to prove it to?

Comment: Anyway, a generic code won't do of course, as one has to use the RTOS *special* capabilities to see the difference, such as time-critical tasks. And of course, a general-purpose OS is not guaranteed *not* to behave as an RTOS.

Comment: Real-time means guaranteed deadlines, not speed. So what you can do is for example to have a thread toggle an I/O pin once per 1ms then measure the square wave with a scope. Look for irregularities, there should be none.

Comment: An alternative to runtime testing is asking the makers of QNX... I'm sure they have way better testing of their system than any reverse engineering you can come up with...

Comment: You see no difference perhaps because there is none, but how are you measuring the time? There is no timing code in your example.

Answer (score 3):

An RTOS does not magically turn your code into "real-time"; rather it *supports* real time by being entirely deterministic.

A general-purpose OS (GPOS) such as Linux normally uses a round-robin equal priority time-sharing scheduler, scharing time "fairly" amongst a number of processes.  As such the more processed running and the busier they are (using more of their available time slice), the less responsive it becomes.

An RTOS on the other hand typically has a pre-emptive priority based scheduler, such that the highest priority ready task gets to run immediately, regardless, and will continue to run until it suspends itself or a higher priority task becomes ready.  In such a system you have to assign priorities appropriately to guarantee all tasks run on time every time.  Generally the tasks with the shortest and most deterministic run-time should have the highest priority.  Critically while an RTOS supports real-time deterministic behaviour a great deal of responsibility is placed on the developer to design tasks and priorities appropriately.

As such you cannot simply run some arbitrary third-party code and expect to demonstrate real-time performance.  You need to code a specific test.  At its simplest you might have a process that blocks on a short period periodic timer, and in that task get the real time passed and analyse how much timing jitter you observe. The real-time system should have minimal jitter (depending on its priority and higher level tasks or interrupts that run), and will not be affected by lower priority tasks, while the GPOS will exhibit much greater variability, especially when running other tasks.

There is a real-time scheduler option for a Linux build, but it is far from perfect.  If you find yourself in ICU on life support, be a bit worried if the respirator is running Linux!

Comment: Linux actually does not use a round-robin equal priority time-sharing scheduler - the [CFS scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) is the current default Linux scheduling algorithm. Most modern scheduling algorithms, CFS included, use schemes to prioritize IO heavy tasks, in order to allow these tasks to be more responsive

Comment: @user129137 OK, but not real-time is the take-home here.  I may look at it again later.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that "real time" means the goal is to minimize the worst case time. Typically this involves sacrificing the average case time, which means that often "real time" means "slower on average".

This also means that to compare the "real-time-ness" of operating systems you want to measure the worst case time (not the average time).

For a random example, imagine if you did the same operation (e.g. allocate some pages of RAM) 50 million times; and found that on one OS the worst case time was 5000 nanoseconds (but it always took 5000 nanoseconds, so the average case time is also 5000 nanoseconds); and found that on the other OS the worst case time is 7000 nanoseconds but it almost always takes 100 nanoseconds (and the average case time is 123 nanoseconds). By comparing the worst case times (5000 vs 70000) you know that the first OS is a better real-time OS. By comparing the average case times (5000 vs. 123) you know that the second OS is a better "not real-time" OS.

Note that most modern CPUs (e.g. 80x86) aren't designed for real-time. To measure the actual worst case you need multiple "unlikely" things to happen at the same time (e.g. CPU getting hot and being forced into "go slow to avoid melting" mode at the same time that chipset interrupts the OS with system management stuff, at the same time that other CPUs and/or devices happen to be pounding memory or buses/links; while you're trying to measure worst case time). In other words, it's going to take a significant amount of effort (and many attempts) just to arrange conditions to be "just right" to hit the worst case.